# Using separate cells rather than separate arrays

Tags: ios, uitableview

In Big Nerd Ranch Book:— iOS Programming (3rd ed.), there is a Bronze Challenge in Ch9 page-205.We have to display 2 sections , 1 displaying items> and other with items<=
I know how to solve this challenge using two separate arrays, one storing expensive items and the other storing cheaper items. But i did not want to solve this problem that way. I want two different types of cells wherein type1 points to expensive ones and is adjusted in section0. And type2 pointing to cheaper ones and getting placed in section1. 
I've attempted this but without any success. Here's the code:-
**This one's for configuring the number of rows in each section:**

```
   - (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
  {
      //#warning Incomplete method implementation.
      // Return the number of rows in the section.
      int numberOfRowsWithValueLessThanOrEqualToFifty=0, numberOfRowsWithValueMoreThanFifty=0;
       NSLog(@"No. of BNRItems- %d", [[[BNRItemStore sharedStore] allItems] count]);
       for (BNRItem *item in [[BNRItemStore sharedStore] allItems])
       {
            //BNRItem *p=[[[BNRItemStore sharedStore] allItems] objectAtIndex:i];
            if ([item valueInDollars]>50) 
            {
                 numberOfRowsWithValueMoreThanFifty++;
            }
            else
            {
                 numberOfRowsWithValueLessThanOrEqualToFifty++;
            }
       }

       if (section==0) {
            return numberOfRowsWithValueMoreThanFifty; //no. of rows in section0
       }
       else{
           return numberOfRowsWithValueLessThanOrEqualToFifty;//no. of rows in section1
       }

     }
```

**This one's for configuring the two cells and returning either one of them based on specific case:**

```
   - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath  *)indexPath
   {
        NSLog(@"hello");

        static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
        static NSString *CellIdentifier2 = @"Cell2";

        UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
        UITableViewCell *cell2 = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier2];
        //Configure the cell...
        if (!cell) {
            cell= [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
        }
        if (!cell2) {
            cell2= [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault           reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier2];
        }

        BNRItem *p= [[[BNRItemStore sharedStore] allItems] objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        if([p value] >50)
        {
            [[cell textLabel] setText:[p description]];
        }
        else{
            [[cell2 textLabel] setText:[p description]];
        }

        if (indexPath.section==0) {
            return cell;
        }
        else{
            return cell2;
        } 
 }
```

Now the code has a bunch of problems. If the first **if** clause runs in conjunction with the second **else** clause the whole purpose of being selective about what goes in section0 and section1 gets destroyed. In the above code the only valid case would be when the 2 **if** clauses run together or when 2 **else** clauses run together . But clearly thats not gonna happen coz the control flow could be random. So does that mean one cannot solve this challenge using two separate types of cells for 2 different sections but have to create separate arrays for storing cheap and expensive items first and then shoving them off into section0 and section1 appropriately?? Pls. advice coz this way was my first idea to solve this problem and i really want it done this way.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you first check the price and then dequeue (or create) corresponding table cell?
Like this:

```
- (UITableViewCell*) tableView:(UITableView*) tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath*) indexPath
{
NSLog(@"hello");
static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
static NSString *CellIdentifier2 = @"Cell2";
UITableViewCell* cell = nil;
NRItem *p= [[[BNRItemStore sharedStore] allItems] objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
if (indexPath.section==0)
{
    cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (!cell)
    {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }
    [[cell textLabel] setText:[p description]];
}
else
{
    cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier2];
    if (!cell)
    {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier2];
    }
    [[cell textLabel] setText:[p description]];
}
return cell;
}
```